# When does ReST become SOAP?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

Let's say I have a server somewhere that takes HTTP gets and returns JSON responses.

Pretty clearly a ReST service, right?

Now let's say it returns XML. Still ReSTful, right?

Okay, now let's say it's an HTTP POST with a payload of XML that returns XML.

And let's also say there's a WSDL in there that defines the service.

And then let's say the XML isn't really messages (which I guess both SOAP and ReST facilitate) but more like passing objects/ontologies.

And then let's say human beings never go to that URL to look at anything, it's only used by apps, browsers, cyborgs, etc.

At what point does my ReSTful service become a SOAP service?

Is there a common place to draw the line, or is it more like a general feel kind of thing?

Are there more better factors that can determine this than the criteria I mentioned?

Comment: REST is not about messages. In REST, representations of resources are passed between client and server. Take a look at http://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presence of a WSDL file clearly is a mark of SOAP. All the other points you mention are not against the REST principles.

Comment: That seems like a practical answer. It looks like some folks use WSDL's with ReST, though: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/

Comment: Wow. That article should really be titled, "IBM - where software innovation goes to die". SOAP fanatics have such a hard time letting go of their WSDL life preservers, and this article is Exhibit A. Truly a depressing read.